# Reading from a certain line onwards in python

Tags: python

Is it possible to read from a certain line onwards? In the example I cited below, I had want to read and use only from Line04 onwards

```
with open (fileList[0], 'rt') as filehandle:
     for line in filehandle:
         print line

# Output:
# This is a testing file
#
# v 1.05
# v -2.15
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
with open('your_file', 'rt') as filehandle:
  lines = filehandle.readlines()[4:]

for line in lines:
    print line
    #do something
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just skip over the first four lines, using [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) to count them:

```
with open(fileList[0], 'rt') as filehandle:
    for line_num, line in enumerate(filehandle):
        if line_num < 4:
            continue

        print line
        # and do anything else
```

Comment: I guess this is the best way. Was looking for a way to use `seek`, but that isn't going to work.

Answer (score 1):

```
lineno = 0
for line in filehandle:
    lineno = lineno + 1
    if(lineno > 4):
        print line
```